# Find and replace special character string in mulitiple text file using perl script command

Tags: perl

I am using the below single line command for replacing words

```
perl -i -p -e 's/old/new/g;' *.config
```

which works fine for  normal string. However if i want to replace a string with special characters like below it doesn't work.

```
perl -i -p -e 's/{{'TEXT' | translate}}/{{'TEXT.T.D' | translate}}/g;' *.config
```

oldText will be like = `{{'TEXT' | translate}}`

New text will be like  = `{{'TEXT.T.D' | translate}}`

Comment: `s/\Q{{'TEXT' | translate}}/../`check perldoc -f quotemeta

Comment: hai Сухой27 , thanks  for the valuable comment . I tried perl -i -p -e 's/\Q{{'TEXT' | translate}}/{{'TEXT.T.D' | translate}}/g;' *.config  ...However it doesn't replace the old value

Comment: Your actual code and/or data differs from what you posted above. `=>` https://eval.in/790023

Answer (score 1):

The `|` symbol is a metacharacter in regular expressions (it means "or"). In order to use it to mean itself, you need to escape it with a backslash.

```
s/{{'TEXT' \| translate}}/{{'TEXT.T.D' | translate}}/g
```

Another alternative (which will escape all potentially problematic characters in the regex) is to use the `\Q` ("quotemeta") escape sequence.

```
s/\Q{{'TEXT' | translate}}/{{'TEXT.T.D' | translate}}/g
```